# Google Sheets: Overwrite value of cell only under certain conditions

Tags: google-sheets

In Google Sheets, I'm looking to automatically overwrite the value of a cell B1 with the value of cell A1 except when the value in A1 is 100.

Cell A1 updates dynamically from an external source.

Can anyone offer me some guidance?

Thanks in advance for your time.

C

Comment: What have you tried already? what's the external source? if it's a ticker or something like that you'll only be able to do it periodically

Comment: I have a list of site pages for which I check google rankings.  The ranking changes/updates when I open the sheet.  The problem is that it doesn't always "fire" and in those cases I get a "100" result.  My objective is to update a page's ranking when I get a good value from google.  When it doesn't "fire" and I get a "100" result, I don't want to overwrite the previous value.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a default value that you would like to replace B1 with if A1=100, then you can use the following formula in B1

```
=if(A1<>100,A1,"default value")
```

Otherwise keeping the value in B1 unchanged is not possible in google sheets at the moment. Although in Excel, this would be the case of 'iterative calculation'.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time @newLearner.  Is there a workaround that you can suggest?  I detailed the business logic in a comment to Robin above.

Comment: If you haven't tried the function above by Robin, go ahead and give it a try. I am not sure about any other way.

Answer (score 0):

This will not be possible with plain formulas as they are not able to memorize the value before the cell has been updated.

I'm still not entirely sure how the data gets into the spreadsheet but the following function will copy all values from `A1:A100` to `B1:B100` that are not 100.

```
function conditionalUpdate(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet7");
  var newData = ss.getRange("A1:A100").getValues();
  var oldData = ss.getRange("B1:B100").getValues();

  for (var row = 0; row < newData.length; ++row) {
    if (newData[row][0] != 100) {
      oldData[row][0] = newData[row][0];
    }
  }
  ss.getRange("B1:B100").setValues(oldData);
}
```

Depending on when the data gets put into the spreadsheet (if it is done before you open it) you can set up an onOpen trigger in <kbd>Tools</kbd><kbd>Script Editor</kbd><kbd>Resources</kbd><kbd>Current Project's triggers</kbd> to run it whenever the Spreadsheet is opened.
Otherwise, since the results won't change, you could have it execute every minute or so.

Comment: Brilliant.  Thanks Robin.

Comment: If this helped you can you please accept the answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Amatuer alert:
I made a cheat work-around method of making this work for myself. I had a query search box that some would paste values into from other worksheets. The problem was that it brang other conditional formatting with those pastes and changed the format of that query search box.

1. I made a default text in cell A2: "** Please do not paste data here **"
2. I then created an array formula in B1: =iferror(arrayformula(A1:B2))
3. I just hid the text in B1 with the same color as background (I later hid that row instead)

So, I get to have a default value in B2 that my employees can overwrite legitimately. The 'error' for B1 is hidden and irrelevant.

It was an easy fix for a minor problem.